# CSocket programming

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, mfc, network-programming

I'm writing code about a system that consist of a server handling multiple client connection.


https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1IeZBO9jqxbXcZPvX6bsAjcM8O3L9KJW7C8UVELa-jUM/edit?hl=en_US
[The link above is the image about the brief idea of how it works](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1IeZBO9jqxbXcZPvX6bsAjcM8O3L9KJW7C8UVELa-jUM/edit?hl=en_US)


In the server I use a CDocument-derived class to manage the socket objects and data, as my computer has multiple network adapters, I need a link list to manage the server listening sockets.


I've got no problem of initializing the sockets to different adapters. But I have encounter a problem of passing the connection request to Client Socket list. I can override the Notification Functions(e.g. OnRecieve, OnAccept) but I don't know how to refer the action in the socket(for example changing the data of document class with the data received) back to the document class.


I'm using VS2010 on Windows 7 Ultimate.


Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create `CSocket` directly, but derive a class

```
CMySocket : CSocket {
   CDocument *m_doc; // or CDocument &m_doc;
}
```

Then never create a `CSocket` but always your `CMySocket` with `m_doc` set to your document. That way you can access the document from socket.